# Calling a function from a HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I wonder what I am doing wrong in this case? I got this button which is an HTML element. When I click on it, I want the function push() to get activated. Unfortunally my console says:

> ReferenceError: push is not defined

Can some one help me in this case? Thanks so much!

```html
<button type="button" onclick=push()>Click Me!</button> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function push (){.....};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of the push() function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change `onclick=push()` to `onclick="push()"` to make it work!

Also, there might be something wrong in the body of the push function because of which it is not able to compile - hence, the error.

Comment: If there's no white space after the = than the quotes aren't necessary

Answer (score -1):

You could do these instead :

You can do this if you want to use the function push() with only one button,

```
<button type="button" id="clickme">Click Me!</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", function() {.....}

</script>
```

And this if you want to use the function push() with multiple button,

```
<button type="button" id="clickme">Click Me!</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementsByClassName("clickme").addEventListener("click", function() {.....}

</script>
```

Pros : Less HTML
Cons : More javascript

Comment: Isn't getElementById the better choice in this case?

Comment: @Suppe Yes it is, class is for multiple elements, and id for only one element, so in this case it's GetElementById